# How to make a Class expand or decrease Attributes based on the need of the Object being created. (C++)

Tags: c++

So, recently I was tasked with making a very simple C++ copy of what a TV could do, the guidelines were to be able to have it with 10 different channels, being able to turn it on and off, change volume (1 bar at a time), change the channel. Like a real TV the ability to do things like changing the volume and channel should only be allowed if the TV is indeed ON.

Now, the code below, at least so far and from my tests does everything I was tasked to do. It is also worth mentioning that at this point, the tests are to be done by calling the respective functions in the Code and not generate user input.

Finally, my question:

If I want different TVs to have a different number of channels what changes and implementations do I have to do? I am **NOT** allowed to use dynamic memory for this.

For example, First has 10 channels.
Now I want to create Second with 3 channels and Third with 20 channels.

PS: Apologies for the Title, I didn't really know how to word the question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class TV{
    
    string Ch1;
    string Ch2;
    string Ch3;
    string Ch4;
    string Ch5;
    string Ch6;
    string Ch7;
    string Ch8;
    string Ch9;
    string Ch10;
    string ChNow;
    int state;
    int sound;
    
public:
    
    TV(string c1, string c2, string c3, string c4, string c5, string c6, string c7, string c8, string c9, string c10);
    void OnAndOff();
    void ChangeSound(char change);
    void ChangeCh(int ch);
    
};

int main(){
    
    TV First("ABC", "BBC", "Housewives", "MovieTV", "Hello World", "Sports News", "Fox News", "Not News", "Politics And News", "Cooking With Gordon");
    
    }

TV::TV(string c1, string c2, string c3, string c4, string c5, string c6, string c7, string c8, string c9, string c10){
    
    Ch1 = c1;
    Ch2 = c2;
    Ch3 = c3;
    Ch4 = c4;
    Ch5 = c5;
    Ch6 = c6;
    Ch7 = c7;
    Ch8 = c8;
    Ch9 = c9;
    Ch10 = c10;
    ChNow = c1;
    
    state = 0;
    sound = 0;
    
}

void TV::OnAndOff(){
    
    // 0 == OFF
    // 1 == ON
    
    if(state == 0){
        state = 1;
        cout << endl << "TV On." << endl;
    } else if(state == 1){
        state = 0;
        cout << endl << "TV Off." << endl;
    } else{
        cout << endl << "Something is wrong." << endl;
    }
    
}

void TV::ChangeSound(char change){
    
    if(state == 1){
    if(change == '+' && sound >= 0 && sound < 10){
        sound = sound+1;
        cout << endl << "Sound: " << sound << endl;
    }else if(change == '+' && sound == 10){
        cout << endl << "Sound: " << sound << endl;
    }else if(change == '-' && sound > 0 && sound <= 10){
        sound = sound-1;
        cout << endl << "Sound: " << sound << endl;
    }else if(change == '-' && sound == 0){
        cout << endl << "Sound: " << sound << endl;
    }else{
        cout << endl << "Press + ou - to change the sound value." << endl;
    } 
    
}else if(state == 0){
    cout << endl << "TV is Off. Unable to change sound value." << endl;
}else{
    cout << endl << "The TV is suffering from an error." << endl;
}
    
}

void TV::ChangeCh(int ch){
    
    if(state == 1){
        switch(ch){
            case 1:
                ChNow = Ch1;
                cout << endl << ChNow << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                ChNow = Ch2;
                cout << endl << ChNow << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                ChNow = Ch3;
                cout << endl << ChNow << endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                ChNow = Ch4;
                cout << endl << ChNow << endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                ChNow = Ch5;
                cout << endl << ChNow << endl;
                break;
            case 6:
                ChNow = Ch6;
                cout << endl << ChNow << endl;
                break;
            case 7:
                ChNow = Ch7;
                cout << endl << ChNow << endl;
                break;
            case 8:
                ChNow = Ch8;
                cout << endl << ChNow << endl;
                break;
            case 9:
                ChNow = Ch9;
                cout << endl << ChNow << endl;
                break;
            case 10:
                ChNow = Ch10;
                cout << endl << ChNow << endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout << endl << "Unable to change to this channel." << endl;
        }
    }else if(state == 0){
        cout << endl << "TV Off. Unable to change channel." << endl;
    }else{
        cout << endl << "The TV has encountered an error." << endl;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You need dynamic memory allocation, there are no good alternatives. The only thing I could think of is making `TV` a template (with the amount of channels being a template parameter).

Comment: This looks like a class/school assignment. If so, your question may be ignored.

Comment: *Hint*: Having the sequence `ch1`, `ch2`, ... , `ch10` suggests that you can use an array (or something like an array, such as `std::vector`). If by *"dynamic memory"* you mean *"explicitly using `new`, `delete`, `malloc`, etc"*, then you could try `std::vector` (although technically vector internally uses dynamic memory allocation). If you want to follow HolyBlackCat's suggestion (i.e. using a template), [here](https://godbolt.org/z/b98frx) is an example that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the C++ STL ("std::") uses the heap underneath, you don't need to allocate any space with "new" or "malloc". Use std::vector instead of all of the declared strings.